# How to store the current logged user id or active user id in odoo 9?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

In expenses, anyone has to approve the expense list, I want to display which user is Approved that?

I just select all res.users as one2many

```
approved_by=fields.Many2one('res.users','Approved By')
```

In XML

```
<field name="approved_by" />
```

Here it will display all users. But I want to display only logged user and it must be selected as default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Environment stores various contextual data used by the ORM. For more details [Odoo Environment](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/orm.html#environment)

Try with following code.

```
approved_by = fields.Many2one('res.users','Approved By', default=lambda self: self.env.user)
```

**EDIT**

With following code, we can also get User id.

```
approved_by = fields.Many2one('res.users','Approved By', default=lambda self: self.env.uid)
```

Answer (score 4):

Define a default value on the field, the default value will be a function that returns the current user's id which can be accessed with `self.env.uid`

```
def get_user_id(self):
    return self.env.uid

approved_by=fields.Many2one('res.users','Approved By', default=_get_user_id)
```

If you want the field to be edited/changed just set `readonly=True`

Answer (score 2):

You can use below code:

```
context = self._context
current_uid = context.get('uid')
user = self.env['res.users'].browse(current_uid)
```

Comment: I Think this is the best answer